# Use different colors for every another grep

Tags: linux, colors, grep

How can I configure `grep` so that I could highlight in color smarter? By using different colors?

Problem: `grep --color` defaults to using red to highlight matches, but it still difficult to read for consecutive runs. If I run `grep` three times, I would like the first run to use red, the second to use some other color (say, green), the third to use red again, and so on.

I read before there is a hack to swap the color in terminal use every another run, so that output will be clean and easier to read. But I forget what that is; is it zsh or bash-script, or some other shell?

Answer (score 3):

You could add the following to your `.bashrc` file:

```
my_grep() {
  if $GREP_USE_FIRST_COLOR
  then
    export GREP_USE_FIRST_COLOR=false
    export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'
  else
    export GREP_USE_FIRST_COLOR=true
    export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;33:mc=01;33:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'
  fi
  grep --color=auto "$@"
}
alias grep=my_grep
```

This will alter the match highlighting color of subsequent `grep` calls in an interactive shell between bold red (`ms=01;31`) and bold yellow (`ms=01;33`).

See [the grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#Environment-Variables) for more information on how to use `GREP_COLORS` to set the particular highlighting colors you like.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [Simple way to colour alternate output lines in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831633/1928610).

If the answer seems a bit confusing, follow this.

1. You have to use a script that automatically does this for you. Open up "terminal". (In many Ubuntu variations and itself, you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to invoke that.) I'm assuming you to be using Ubuntu.
2. Use your favorite editor to open a text file for writing the script. I'm using 'nano'. Like this `nano ~/grepc.sh`. This opens a file called `grepc.sh` in my /home (`~/`).
3. Paste this bash script into that.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   while read line
   do
     echo -e '\e[1;31m'"$line"
     read line
     echo -e '\e[1;32m'"$line"
   done
   echo -en '\e[0m'
   ```
4. If you're in nano, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will attempt to close nano, but before that it will ask if you want to save the file. Do so, by pressing **y** on your keyboard.
5. Now you have to make this script executable. Type the command `chmod +x ~/grepc.sh`.
6. That's it. Now use this with grep commands like this: `ls ~/ | grep "test" | ./grepc.sh` (Assuming the command is executed in /home).

Comment: I think you read my question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by answer of @Chriki

By using PROMPT_COMMAND as a hook and update the GREP_COLOR and git config for every prompt.

```
# .bashrc
# ...
# your alias, git prompt, git completetion, exports... etc
# ...
__grep_swap_color ()
{
  if [ -z "$GREP_COLOR" ]
  then
    export GREP_COLOR='1;32'
    git config --global color.grep.match blue
  else
    export GREP_COLOR=''
    git config --global color.grep.match red
  fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND';__grep_swap_color'
# End of file
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me inspire you :-) Please let me point you to a few drawbacks of your solution:  (1) You won’t get the color alteration whenever you execute another shell command between two grep runs or when you just hit Enter after a grep run;  (2) Your solution is a bit expensive in that it runs quite a bit of code for _every_ new prompt;  (3) Your bash will complain on each prompt when `PROMPT_COMMAND` is not set because the prompt command will then start with a `;`;  (4) `GREP_COLOR` is [deprecated](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#Environment-Variables).

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaptation of [Kimvais’ solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831633/1672723)
(which Unrealist also used).  Create `grepc.bash`:

```
while read line
do
     echo "$line"
     read line && echo "$line" | sed $'s/\(\e\[\([0-9]+;\))*\)31m/\\132m/g'
done
```

This uses `sed` to change the escape sequence for red to the escape sequence for green
in alternate lines of its input.  Use, for example, as

```
grep --color=always (whatever) (whatever) | (path to the script)/grepc.bash
```

It seems that `grep --color` actually uses color
only if it’s writing to the terminal (window),
and you need to use `=always` to get it to use color when it’s writing to a pipe. 
And BTW, it’s conventional to put personal utilities like this into `~/bin`,
and then add that to your PATH, so you don’t need to specify it when you run the utility.

Comment: I was not asking every another line, but every another run